# Is it possible to use Quarkus 2.0 hibernate orm extension with standard JPA and jakarta.persistence packages?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, quarkus

I have an environment that already depends on **jakarta**.persistence packages for JPA. Is there a way to use **jakarta**.persistence packages with quarkus 2.0? quarkus-hibernate-orm still seems to depend on **javax**.persistence instead of **jakarta**.persistence.

I can use early adopters approaches ...

Answer (score 1):

Currently that is not possible as Quarkus does not use the jakarta namespaces anywhere

Comment: Is there any timeplan for this? As far as I can see there already is quite a some support in quarkus 2.0 for the jakarta namespace (e.g. jakarta.activation, jakarta.inject, jakarta.json ...).

Comment: There is no concrete timeframe yet.

Comment: Jakarta EE 9 with new pakages "jakarta.*" was released in 06 Nov 2020. It is very important to use these packages in Quarkus, otherwise we would loose new Jakarta EE features, and the whole idea with moving to Open Source would be broken. I guess the Microprofile has to be converted to the new packages and maybe we are waiting for this transformation.